# jQuery UI dialog doesn't close when I click my other tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a jQuery UI dialog that I would like to close when I click outside it. That works, but when I click my other tab on my site it will still remain open.
This is my script to close it when I click outside it:

```
jQuery('html')
  .bind(
    'click',
    function(e) {
      if (
        jQuery('#dialog').dialog('isOpen') &&
        !jQuery(e.target).is('.ui-dialog, a') &&
        !jQuery(e.target).closest('.ui-dialog').length
      ) {
        jQuery('#dialog').dialog('close');
      }
    }
  );
```

But like I said, when I click one of my tabs on the site it will still remain open.

Comment: Please provide your HTML too. Maybe your tab is a link then it messes with `!jQuery(e.target).is('.ui-dialog, a')`

Comment: I guess your other tabs stop click event propagation